# Equivalent of .htaccess in NGINX

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` file. I am trying to configure this on `NGINX` with no luck.

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My current `NGINX` configuration is on `ajenti` hosting panel.

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels

Comment: This isn't a question about web hosting control panels, though; it's a standard nginx question.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head,

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$uri;
```

should do the trick.